# How to access partition columns in dask data frame, which was loaded from partitioned parquet table

Tags: python, dataframe, dask

I have saved dask dataframe as parquet with partitions using following command:

```
df.to_parquet('some path', engine='pyarrow',
              partition_on=['Year','Month','Day'], write_index=True)
```

After that I have loaded the same parquet folder using the following command:

```
df = dd.read_parquet(path, engine='pyarrow')
```

The question is, how can I get columns, which were used as partition columns? 
If I try to access them in a normal way, like df.Day or df.Year, they are not present in the dataframe. I have tried to load the same parquet table using Pandas, and the columns were there as all other columns.

Does anybody have any idea, how can I access partition columns in dask data frame?

Any assistance would be greatly appreciated!

Best,
Michael

Comment: This is fixed with the `'fastparquet'` engine in https://github.com/dask/dask/pull/3171

Comment: There is no deviations in this regards with pandas between both engines.. is it different for dask ?

Comment: Thank you for letting me know. I will try to save my tables with fastparquet engine. I think the parquet files produces by both engines are not really compatible.

Comment: The output from both engines is in theory compatible, but pyarrow does not produce a metadata file (by default), so for fastparquet you must explicitly list all the data files you want to load from.

Comment: There was a bug in `pyarrow` that did not add these columns to the `meta` object. This will be fixed with the next `pyarrow==0.9.0` release.

Comment: Thank you, I will give it a try when 0.9 is available.